# Finding the derivative and the differential of $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ at $a=(1,2)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f:(x,y) \mapsto x^2-y^2$. I want to find the differential of this function and the derivative at the point $a=(1,2)$ on the vector $v=(3,5)$.

For the derivative on the vector $v$ I did this:

$$f'(a)=\frac{f(a+tv)-f(a)}{t}$$ as $t$ tends to $0$

Which gives:

$$\frac{f((1,2)-t(3,5))-f(1,2)}{t}=\frac{f((1-3t,2-5t)-f(1,2)}{t} = \frac{(1-3t)^2-(2-5t)^2-1+4}{t}=\frac{4t-19t^2}{t}=4-19t$$

And $4-19t \rightarrow 4$ as $t$ tends to $0$.

Is is my reasoning correct?

Now about the differential. Suppose we want to find at some point $a$ the differential. We have:

$$d_{f_{a}}(u)=d_{f_{a}}(u_1e_1)+d_{f_{a}}(u_2e_2)=u_1d_{f_{a}}(e_1)+u_2d_{f_{a}}(e_2)$$

In case $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$, we have:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=2x$$ and $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=-2y$$

And the vector $a=(1,2)$ in the base $(e_1,e_2)$ where $e_1=(1,0) \:\:e_2=(0,1)$ is $a=1e_1+2e_2$.

So the differential will be $$d_{f_{a}}=1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,0)+2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,1) $$ Am I correct?

Comment: $d_{f_{a}}=1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,0)+2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,1) =5.$ What made you not say that the result is $5$?

Comment: @zoli I forgot to really calculate the final result as I was more interested in the overall logic behind the calculations.